# Is there any performance issue when passing big "built-in" object to a function?

Tags: javascript

I created a function that takes [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object and do some stuff with `.clientX` and `.clientY` properties. Is there any performance issue based on that I am passing whole object, not just properties I will use? Is this object passed by reference? Should I pass whole object or just the properties I will use in the function?

Let's consider following examples:

1)

```
function doSomethingWithMousePos(event) {
  return {
    // Do some stuff with data
    x: event.clientX * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    y: event.clientY * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
  }
}

doSomethingWithMousePos(event);
```

or

2)

```
function doSomethingWithMousePos(x, y) {
  return {
    // Do some stuff with data
    x: x * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    y: y * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
  }
}


doSomethingWithMousePos(event.clientX, event.clientY);
```

Which approach is better? Or it does not matter at all?

Comment: In JS, objects are always passed by reference. Therefore, if you were to pass values - that would incur more overhead. Your approach is fine IMO.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Sorry, that is just an brief example, In fact im doing complex canvas operations inside this function.

Comment: @Mjh Alright, that's great. I was alredy using 1) but I thought for a moment that 2) might be faster. Thanks for clarification anyway.

Comment: This is a question more about abstraction and separation of concerns.  I think the correct answer is "it depends".  Do you want your consumer of `getMousePos` to need to worry about the innards of the `event` object or just let `getMousePos` deal with it?  Do you want `getMousePos` to be callable from multiple consumers that each supply their own `x` and `y` values?

Comment: ...I wouldn't worry about speed here and concentrate more on maintainability and logical correctness.  If/when you prove there is a speed issue through proper profiling, _then_ start worrying about such micro optimisations, but do it in a smart manner based on actual results.

Comment: I agree with accepted answer - whatever you and your team find more readable or maintainable  should be the way to go. As for actual speed, it's slower to pass by value. However, today's hardware and software are so advanced that you can almost never notice such overhead since everything happens and microsecond or nanosecond level. Sure, if you had like 1GB of source code that dealt with passing by value - that would eat away at your RAM. Anyway, whatever happens - good luck to you and have fun with the project and happy new year :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript objects are passed by reference, so it's really six of one, half a dozen of the other. You'll have to access those properties at one point or another, so whether it's in the line that calls the method or inside the method, it doesn't really matter. Arguably the best approach would be whatever you and your team find more readable.